# Select all customers and all orders with single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way with single mysql query to output all customers and all their orders including customers without orders? I have:

Customers:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Orders:

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  id   ║ ClientID ║ Status║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 1     ║        1 ║  wait ║
║ 2     ║        1 ║  rdy  ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

How do I select a result like:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║ Order Id    ║ Order Status║
╠════╬═════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║           1 ║        wait ║
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║           2 ║        rdy  ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║             ║             ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Have you looked at using a join?

Comment: Research joins and try having a go yourself: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a left join between the two tables:

```sql
SELECT c.ID, c.NAME, o.id AS OrderId, o.Status AS OrderStatus
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.ClientID = c.ID
ORDER BY c.ID, o.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, with some tweaking that did exactly the task i needed!